# HTML/CSS - Put img on top of img?

Tags: html, image, overlay

I have two png's. One is the actual image, another is a mostly transparent image with a sticker price icon in the top right. I know I could combine these in photoshop and just create one image.

But I need these to be generated dynamically, for a bunch of different base images.

**Is there some way to code the "actual image" and then use code to overlay the "transparent sticker image"?**

Answer (score 12):

Sure, the easiest way would be to absolutely position both images within their container:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <img src="main-image.jpg" style="position:absolute;"/>
    <img src="overlay-image.png" style="position:absolute;"/>
</div>
```

The `position:relative` on the container is needed for absolute positioning of children to work.  Of course, if the container is itself absolutely positioned already, then that's fine.

The `position:absolute` is *not* needed on the base image if both images are in the top-left corner, but having it allows you to tweak its placement if needed.

You could also use static position on the main image and relative position on the overlay image:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <img src="main-image.jpg" style="width:100px"/>
    <img src="overlay-image.png" style="position:relative; left:-100px"/>
</div>
```

but for this to work you'd need to know the width of the base image.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the images in a `<div>` with the overlay image first and the actual image second, and can set the css of the div to `position: relative`.

The two images can then be given the css `{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}`.

```
<div style="position:relative;">  
  <img src="overlay.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">  
  <img src="actual.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">  
</div>`
```

If you really want to be safe, you can set the `z-index` of each image.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the position attribute to relative or absolute, set the left and top attributes to the desired values, then set the z-index attribute to 1 (assuming that you don't have other z-index properties already set). Keep in mind that the place where the image is supposed to render without the changed top and left attributes, there will be a space where it should be.